# Dropzone is uploading all files to server for each file drop/selection

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to integrate dropzone in a laravel 8 application. Whenever I drop any image in dropzone, it is uploading all the files of dropzone, not skipping already uploaded file. For example, if I drop "image-1.jpg" in dropzone, it uploads the file instantly (which is desired). But after that, if I select "image-2.jpg", it re-uploads "image-1.jpg" first (which isn't desired, I want to prevent this re-upload), then it uploads "image-2.jpg". Also, I want to prevent folder(containing multiple image) upload and have tried to prevent it by setting maxFiles to 1, but it's not preventing it.

### Javascript

```
    var refType = $('#reference-type');
    electronic = $('.electronic'),
    image = $('.image'), 
    description = $('.description'),
    url = "{{ route('user.bank.files') }}",
    submitRef = $('#submit-ref');
    
    Dropzone.autoDiscover=false;
    var imageDropzone;
    var config = { 
        url: url, headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'{{ csrf_token() }}'},
        uploadMultiple: false,
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 1,
        paramName: 'reference_image',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg, image/png , image/jpg, image/svg',
        init: function() {
            imageDropzone = this;
        },
        removedfile: function (file) {
            if (file.accepted) {
                data = {
                    action: 'delete',
                    tnx_id: "{{ the_tnx(data_get($order, 'tnx')) }}"
                };
                NioApp.Form.toPost(url, data);
            }
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        },
        sending: function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append('action', 'store');
            formData.append('tnx_id', "{{ the_tnx(data_get($order, 'tnx')) }}");
        },
        addedfiles: function () {
            if (this.files.length > 1) {
                this.removeFile(this.files[1]);
                NioApp.Toast("{{ __('You can upload only one :file.', ['file' => 'image']) }}", 'warning');
            }
        },
        error: function(file, errorMessage) {
            $.each(imageDropzone.files, function(i, file) {
                file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED
            });
        }
    };

    $("#reference-image").dropzone({...config});
```

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics#overriding-default-event-handlers): "***Overriding default event handlers**
In general you should never have to do this ...*".  The example they give is even `addedfiles`, which says "*ONLY DO THIS IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING!*".  Why are you overriding `addedfiles`, to do what looks like the default Dropzone behaviour anyway?  Have you tried just removing that?

Comment: If you really need it, have you tried any debugging, eg `console.dir(this.files)` to check what it looks like? My guess is it would be zero-based, so maybe you should be removing `this.files[0]`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic maxfiles option was not working as expected so I used ```addedfiles``` I want to keep the image that was dropped first, so I've removed this.files[1] in the addedfiles event.

Comment: [Here's a bare-bones JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/sn452cd9/) example showing that `maxFiles` works fine.  What exactly is the problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried to remove the extra added file from the preview box. Couldn't click on the Remove file link because of tooltip containing warning message: "You can not upload any more files." So, I used the ```addedfiles``` event to remove the file preview manually.

Comment: I think I see what you mean - the "X" shown on the image might look like it is a "remove" button, like if you click the x it will remove the file. That is not what it is, it just shows there was an error with the upload.  I added the `addRemoveLinks: true` option [to my JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/sn452cd9/), is that what you're after?

Comment: I didn't click on "X", I tried to click on the "Remove file" link but couldn't click on it due to the red tooltip. Suddenly found out my problem. My problem is in the ```error``` event. I used it to re-queue the image in case of server-side validation error. But it eventually causing re-upload of all image.